# Prove that the series is locally uniformly convergent

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n}}{z-n}$$ converges locally uniformly on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ but not uniformly on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

I can't prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^{n}}{z-n}$ converges for every $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{Z}^{+}.$

The question is from *Complex Analysis* by Eberhard Freitag.

Edit: I have been able to prove convergence of series at each point on the domain of definition. How do I prove local uniform convergence and show that the series is not uniformly convergent?

Comment: You can split the series into its imaginary and real parts. Then use the alternating series test for both. If you don't fancy actually calculating real and imaginary parts, you can bound both by the absolute value.

Comment: another way is to group consecutive terms and show a bound $C_K/n^2$ for their absolute value on a compact $K$ avoiding the integers, so the sum paired that way is normally (absolutely/uniformly) convergent on any compact $K$ and this implies the result